# Checking port availability in Linux

Tags: c, linux, port

I need to launch several instances of a game in the same computer using Linux. The game is created launching a server at a specified port number (using a command line command with `--port NUMBER` as an argument) and then each of the players attachs itself to that port to play the game (in a similar fashion).

I need to launch hundreds of games in parallel through a little C program that uses the stdlib.h system library function (`system(const char *command)`) to launch the game server and the game players.

What I need to know is: how can I check from withing that C program that a port is available before launching the game server on that port number? It´s important to note that my program itself does not bind to any port, it just launchs (with system) the program that will actually try to connect to that port.

Comment: What have you tried? I can bet that if you tried the 1st thing that comes to the mind, you would know already, that trying to bind a socket to a port that is already, it would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use bind() directly, and if it doesn't succeed you can try another port.

Checking if a port is free and then binding is not possible and would be a race condition: You just checked, that a port was free, but someone already used it.

Reading /proc/net/tcp can help you though, but the race condition still applies.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is normally trying to open a port and then handle the error as a already used port. A nice example can be found [here](http://systhread.net/texts/200904netconn1.php)

Three simple steps:

1. Try to open socket on the port you desire
2. If it works return true and close the socket
3. If not, return false

In the example given, they do it remotely, but you easily can change that.